# How to check if mobile app is running from NodeJS API server?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, api, express

I am working in an ordering app. We only want to let the customer place an order if the venues have our app running in their tab or mobile whatever. I am not familiar with app technology. I tried to google but got lost. Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The app / client needs to tell you it is running and you then determine whether or not it is actually running at a given time if the last update from the client is e.g. at most 1 minute old. Alternatively you need an open connection via websocket or http long polling which you can send a challenge over and an active client has to respond.

Comment: Thank you @luk2302, any idea how I check if the connection is alive once connected through websocket. I see the existing websocket setup through AWS API gateway but was wondering how would i check if the connection is still alive using those connectionId.